# Opengl with cmake and glew glfw3 and glm libraries

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw, glew

I have a problem compiling [this example](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/#Building_on_Linux) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;

int main(){
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
GLFWwindow* window; // (In the accompanying source code, this variable is global)
window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
if( window == NULL ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental=true; // Needed in core profile
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

do{
    // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it using a single line in terminal with the proper flags, but always finding errors. In several forums i found that is better to use cmake to find, link and compile using the libraries i need, so using [this example](http://igorbarbosa.com/articles/how-to-use-opengl-freeglut-and-cmake/) i tried to program my own cmake lists, obtaining this code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)


#Encontrando y linkeando GLEW
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GLEW_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GLEW_DEFINITIONS})
if(NOT GLEW_FOUND)
 message(Error " GLEW not found")
endif(NOT GLEW_FOUND)

#Encontrando y linkeando glfw3
find_package(GLFW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GLFW_DEFINITIONS})

if(NOT GLFW_FOUND)
        message(Error "GLFW not found")
endif(NOT GLFW_FOUND)

#Encontrando y linkeando glm

find_package(GLM REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GLM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GLM_DEFINITIONS})

if(NOT GLM_FOUND)
        message(Error "GLM not found")
endif(NOT GLM_FOUND)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${OpenGL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${OpenGL_DEFINITIONS})

if(NOT OpenGL_FOUND)
        message(Error "OpenGL not found")
endif(NOT OpenGL_FOUND)

#Incluir archivos

add_executable(abrir main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(abrir ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} ${GLM_LIBRARIES})
```

But I get these errors:

```
Could not find module FindGLEW.cmake or a configuration file for package GLEW.

Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindGLEW.cmake or set GLEW_DIR to the
directory containing a CMake configuration file for GLEW.  The file will
have one of the following names:

GLEWConfig.cmake
glew-config.cmake



Error GLEW not found
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
Could not find module FindGLFW.cmake or a configuration file for package
GLFW.

Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindGLFW.cmake or set GLFW_DIR to the
directory containing a CMake configuration file for GLFW.  The file will
have one of the following names:

GLFWConfig.cmake
glfw-config.cmake



ErrorGLFW not found
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (find_package):
Could not find module FindGLM.cmake or a configuration file for package
GLM.

Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindGLM.cmake or set GLM_DIR to the
directory containing a CMake configuration file for GLM.  The file will
have one of the following names:

GLMConfig.cmake
glm-config.cmake
```

How can I fix these errors?  Or is there an easier way to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try... looking for glew-config.cmake/glfw-config.cmake etc and setting CMAKE_MODULE_PATH accordingly before running cmake?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a "little" late. But if someone else has run into this problem. This is what I did.

I copied this file https://github.com/Groovounet/glm-deprecated/blob/master/util/FindGLM.cmake in my computer i.e /home/user/Libs/cmake/FindGLM.cmake

Then I added this line to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /home/user/Libs/cmake)
```

So my first 3 lines of my file are:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (test)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /home/user/Libs/cmake)
```

Then I run cmake and make and I had no errors.

Comment: This works for those trying to compile the Arrayfire library and receiving glm CMake errors

Answer (score -4):

I strongly recommend you to use Qt Creator for that specific tutorial. At least, I did it in that way. Its always better to use an IDE for those things. I remember I had to rewrite some parts of the CMakeLists file in order to build it correctly to my environment (I did not wanted to use AntTweakBar, for example).

The Qt Creator instructions provided by that tutorial are really good and they should work for you.

Also, remember to install every single package mentioned in that tutorial you're using, including CMake. If I remember well, they should work fine :)